# Playwright not displaying Alert Message

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-java

My application triggers an alert notification after submitting a request and I would like to capture the alert message in the notification using playwright. I have tried the following but still it does not work, Any help here would be appreciated:

My application: The alert captured is shown below

[The alert message looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeZLs.png)

[The alert message is a sl-alert as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrE2.png)

I have tried the following code but it does not work:

```
   page.onDialog(dialog -> System.out.println(dialog.defaultValue()));
   page.click("zero-button:has-text(\'Submit\') >> visible=true");


   page.onDialog(alert -> System.out.println(alert.defaultValue()));
   page.click("zero-button:has-text(\'Submit\') >> visible=true");


   page.onDialog(dialog -> System.out.println(dialog.message()));
   page.click("zero-button:has-text(\'Submit\') >> visible=true");

   page.onDialog(alert -> System.out.println(alert.message()));
   page.click("zero-button:has-text(\'Submit\') >> visible=true");
```

Comment: Posting images in the questions is generally not a good idea. However, as evident from the picture, your transaction message appears under a `shadow-dom`. Have you added code to handle `shadow-dom` in your code? If not you should do that first.

Answer (score 1):

[`page.onDialog`](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-event-dialog) will only intercept modal dialogs opened via `alert`, `prompt` etc. On your page you have a custom html overlay which won't trigger dialog events. You can do something like [`page.waitForSelector("sl-alert")`](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) to wait for the dialog to show up.